# Vue: mounted changed value not passed to component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This is my Vue main file:

```
export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
        FormSelector,
    },
    data () {
        return {
            headerInfo: {
                issue: '',
                model: 'model-1'
            }
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.headerInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('header'))
    },
    methods: {
        selectModel (model) {
            this.headerInfo.model = model
        },
    }
}
```

And this is how I call the component:

```
<FormSelector @select="selectModel" v-bind:model="headerInfo.model"/>
```

On component file, this is the script:

```
export default {
    name: 'FormSelector',
    props: ['model'],
    data () {
        return {
            select: this.model,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        changeModel (e) {
            const model = (e.target.value)
            this.$emit('select', model)
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: how can I change `select` data value when mounted cycle load `headerInfo` data from localStorage?

At this time, only headerInfo data on main file is changed.

Comment: Change `v-bind:model="headerInfo.model` to `v-bind:model="getModel"` where `getModel` is a getter that returns `headerInfo.model`. Then, as soon as `headerInfo` changes that getter will be triggered to update the value.

Comment: @vishal-wadhwa So, I need to call the getter inside to mounted()?

Comment: Why wait for the `mounted` lifecycle hook? Can you not just return the result from local storage directly in the `data()` method.

Comment: No. You don't need to do any changes in mounted. As soon as `headerInfo` is assigned a new value in `mounted` the getter will be triggered automatically and update the value in `FormSelector`.

Comment: BTW, it is working without getter as well. http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/323671/

Comment: @vishal-wadhwa The problem is: the `select` is not grabbing the `model` value: http://jsfiddle.net/rgp9wcvL/

Comment: Found a solution: change the lifecylce hook to created. This hook run before the component creation.

Answer (score 0):

Change method mounted add async and await.

```
async mounted () {
  this.headerInfo = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('header'))
}
```